# Failed to create writable database file

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
2016-02-10 12:35:14.524 FlightTableView[2448:127703] *** Assertion failure in -[AppDelegate copyDatabaseIfNeeded], /Volumes/Data/Nasrin/FlightTableView/FlightTableView/AppDelegate.m:30
2016-02-10 12:35:14.528 FlightTableView[2448:127703] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Failed to create writable database file with message 'The file “Airports.sqlite3” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.'.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001026c1e65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000102138deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001026c1cca +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   Foundation                          0x0000000101d844de -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 198
    4   FlightTableView                     0x0000000101b1529c -[AppDelegate copyDatabaseIfNeeded] + 668
    5   FlightTableView                     0x0000000101b15439 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 89
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000102a661f1 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 272
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000102a67397 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3415
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000102a6dcc6 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1760
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000102a6ae7b -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
    10  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010535c754 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 192
    11  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010535cac2 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001025eda31 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001025e395c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001025e2e13 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001025e2828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000102a6a7cd -[UIApplication _run] + 402
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000102a6f610 UIApplicationMain + 171
    18  FlightTableView                     0x0000000101b18acf main + 111
    19  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001040b992d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

(void) copyDatabaseIfNeeded  Method is given below.

```
   NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager]; 
   NSError *error; NSString *dbPath = [self getDBPath]; 
   BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath]; 
   if(!success) 
       { 
          NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Airports.sqlite"]; 
          success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:dbPath error:&error]; 
   if (!success) NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
```

Comment: Please show the relevant AppDelegate code involved with copying the database.

Comment: Did But same no change...

Comment: NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSString *dbPath = [self getDBPath];
    BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
    if(!success)
    {
        NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Airports.sqlite"];
        success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:dbPath error:&error];
        if (!success)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);

Comment: this is my - (void) copyDatabaseIfNeeded

Comment: Welcome to SO, here is how you should ask a question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Please check what is returned in dbPath. Does it contains a valid path.

Comment: can you please explain this errors to me first what's the reason of this errors

Comment: - (NSString *) getDBPath
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
   // NSLog(@"path: %@",[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Airports.sqlite3"]);
    return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Airpots.sqlite3"];
}

Comment: I would suggest use createfile method of nsfilemanger to create the copy of your sqlite. Hope it helps

Comment: Make sure your project contains "Airports.sqlite".

Comment: i saw it was "Airports.sqlite3" i changed it by"Airports.sqlite" it works but showing black screen rather then showing my data from database

Comment: 2016-02-10 15:20:04.546 FlightTableView[3012:261758] path: /Users/c36/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1ED5869B-440D-4C08-9DD1-11438ECA0FCF/data/Containers/Data/Application/FAAB5B4E-539B-4166-BA9B-4C9EBD1C3814/Documents/Airports.sqlite
2016-02-10 15:20:04.790 FlightTableView[3012:261758] path: /Users/c36/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1ED5869B-440D-4C08-9DD1-11438ECA0FCF/data/Containers/Data/Application/FAAB5B4E-539B-4166-BA9B-4C9EBD1C3814/Documents/Airports.sqlite
************ 
showing this error now.....don't know what to do